# How to add header line to CSV without loading whole file?

Tags: c#

I have a `console application` and I would like to add a `header row` to a CSV file without loading the data into the application. What code do I need to do this but also to check only the first line to see if the headers already exist and if they do then not add the header row? I have tried a few ways of doing this but cannot find a way of coding this without loading the whole file to check if it exists and then add the header row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` to minimize your memory usage.

My suggestion is to read csv file line by line and write it to temp file if you need to add header. Memorywise, it's efficient.

```
private void AddHeader(string filename)
{
    string tempFilename = "temp.csv";
    bool toCopy = false;

    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(tempFilename, false))
    {
        //check if header exists
        using(var sr = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            var line = sr.ReadLine(); // first line
            if(line != null && line != "Your Header") // check header exists
            {
                toCopy = true; // need copy temp file to your original csv

                // write your header into the temp file
                sw.WriteLine("Your Header");

                while(line != null)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(toCopy)
        File.Copy(tempFilename, filename, true);
    File.Delete(tempFilename);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code snippet. But how can I add the headers to the CSV file at the top without overwriting the first row in the file?

Comment: this solution doesn't overwrite the first row

Comment: It adds the row but it adds the headers in the same cell, not in separate cells even though I have separated the headers by commas in the following line: sw.WriteLine("header 1, header 2, header 3") but this is stored in the CSV file as one column and not separate columns. How do I make it store the headers as separate columns?

Comment: could you open your csv file by notepad and post some sample data?

Comment: It sounds like you opened the file in excel. Open it in notepad and lets see what's the separator used in your csv

Comment: It saves the text to the top of the CSV (with your code) but when opening the CSV file in excel it shows it as Header 1, Header 2, Header 3 separated by commas but in one cell (should be in three cells so it lines up with the values in the columns. When I run code that reads the CSV file it cannot find Header 3 for example because it is in one cell with Header 1 and Header 2. So it doesn't seem to be saving it in the same way the CSV data is saved.

Comment: When you mentioned "cell", you are not looking at the original csv file but formatted by excel. Check my previous comment and see what's the separator using in your csv. Csv doesn't necessarily use comma as separator.

Comment: It was because the file was opened in excel. The code loads the CSV data as expected after the headers have been added.

Comment: I am glad the answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can read one line at a time this way, and only add the header if does not exist:

```
// Read in lines from file.
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("c:\\file.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("-- {0}", line);
}
```

https://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readlines

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But how would I add the headers to the CSV file at the top without overwriting the first row in the file?

Comment: In that case, you will have to read the whole  file and create a new string builder, starting with your new row.  Then save the string builder to the file, but the correct answer will work.