# Import Text file into Database in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#

I am creating a form to show a table in a local project database.  The database is empty.  I have a text file with Rolling Stones Top 500 songs. From 500 to 1, each line (500 lines) has this info:  Rank of the song, Artist, Song title.  Here is what it looks like [THIS](https://pastebin.com/N3fyxVKe) if I don't make sense.

I want to have the text file imported via a button.  I have a button ready, but without code inside.

The book hints at reading and tokenizing each line to get these values.  It also suggests opening the XSD file and making an Insert Query to add records. Lastly, it suggests using the "SQL insert command.

I am stuck at this step.
Should this be accomplished with a for loop?

```
     for(//... i <500 //...)
```

How does tokenizing work?
Do I use a relative path for the text file, so any computer can use it?

Comment: You have to build a SQL Insert command for each row.  Look into Dapper, and then understand INSERT INTO...

The path is an implementation detail -- you should have that passed into the command line as an argument, or as a config.  

Btw, you don't have to loop with a for -- read up on reading a file one row at a time, ie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726825/how-to-add-header-line-to-csv-without-loading-whole-file/43726891?noredirect=1#comment74533158_43726891

Comment: This is a bit much, but can help: http://developerpublish.com/dapper-net-guide-inserting-data/

Comment: you need to google how to insert into database from a Textfile there are many ways to skin this cat.. I would suggest you go try something first then come back and post actual code as to what you have tried. also look into how to create a List<Object> meaning a Class that mimics your data file structure and how to create `user types` if you are using Sql Server, so you can pass a List<T> to do bulk Inserts.. you could also create xml file and do bulk inserts into a database using SQL Server Stored procedure..